# CSS3 marquee effect performance issues

Tags: css

I scroll a text with `translate3d`, but the effect suffers from performance issues. With some additional effects running at the same, *sometimes* the text is not scrolling smoothly, even a fast computer. Any ideas for improvements?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h08211dc/)

**HTML:**

```
<p><span>Lorem ipsum...</span></p>
```

**CSS:**

```
p {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

span {
    -webkit-animation: marquee 70s linear infinite;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 100%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: you could try using javascript..maybe with http://famo.us

Comment: why translate3d if you are just using translateX?

Comment: Actually I was initially using `translateX` but I read that using `translate3d` will force hardware acceleration.